# I can't declare variable in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I tried many variation of this but it doesn't seem to work...
I got

> DECLARE is not valid at this position, expecting EOF

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IncrementValue INT;
    SET @IncrementValue = 0;
    SELECT * FROM dc2_evaluasi_dosen WHERE kode_prodi = @IncrementValue;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to declare the variable.
Use below statements.

```
SET @IncrementValue = 0;
SELECT * FROM dc2_evaluasi_dosen WHERE kode_prodi = @IncrementValue;
```

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table dc2_evaluasi_dosen(kode_prodi int,description varchar(50));
 insert into dc2_evaluasi_dosen values(0,'A');
 insert into dc2_evaluasi_dosen values(1,'B');
```

Query:

```
     SET @IncrementValue = 0;
     SELECT * FROM dc2_evaluasi_dosen WHERE kode_prodi = @IncrementValue;
```

Output:

| kode_prodi | description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=25f9dee20783b9f443786dbec95294eb)*

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out but you're faster